# SSL showing 128bit encryption for 2048 bit private key

Tags: ssl, encryption

I have created a `privatekey.key` during SSL creation for `CSR certificate` creation for getting `SSL certificate`. I have purchased the certificate and configured `SSL` in my `Apache server`, after that when I restart the server it stops working, for make it working I have used the following command as follows:

```
C:\Apache24\bin> openssl rsa -in privatekey.key -out privatekey.key
```

After that when I restarted my Apache it is working fine. But now it is showing me that `128 bit encryption`, but I had created the key for 2048 bit encryption. How can I make it `2048 bit encryption`?
Please check the following image:
[image: check encryption]

Comment: Could you please include the exact message in the question?

Comment: @piet.t now it is showing 128bit encryption I need it 2048, hope you got it!!

Comment: Could you please include the EXACT MESSAGE in the question?

Comment: You're confused. 128 bit encryption refers to the session key. 2048 bits refers to the certificate. They aren't the same thing, or comparable in any way.

Comment: @EJP please check image in updated question

Comment: Why? 128 bit encryption still refers to the session key. No further comment necessary. What makes you think you need 2048? You don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got to be aware that SSL/TLS uses hybrid encryption: During the handshake it uses asymmetric encrytpion like RSA to exchange a key for some symmetric encryption-algorithm like AES that is then used to encrypt the traffic. The reason is that asymmetric encrpytion is rather slow compared to symmetric algos, so you use those on the bulk data to get better performance and reduce server-load.

Also take care that asymmetric algorithms require significantly longer keys for the same "strength". While 256-bit AES might sound less secure than 4096-bit RSA they might actually be quite similar from the offered protection.

So while you are using 2048-bit RSA for the key-exchange, 128-bit-AES is used to encrypt the payload.

P.S.: the cipher used during the session is negotiated between client and server from a list of ciphers each support during the SSL-handshake.

Comment: so it you mean it is also safer to use 128bit?? But I prefer to use 2048

Comment: For which part of the conversation? With which encryption-algorithm? There is no symmetric algorithm I know of that uses 2048-bit keys.

Comment: The client does not generate the session key; does not encrypt it; and does not send it. It is negotiated via a key agreement protocol.